# Leetcode 234: Palindrome LinkedList

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am looking at a solution for [234. Palindrome Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/):

> Given the `head` of a singly linked list, return `true` if it is a palindrome.

This is a correct solution:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
        #Null condition
        if head == None:
            return True
        
        #move fast and slow pointers
        s_p = head
        f_p = head
        while(f_p.next != None and f_p.next.next != None):
            s_p = s_p.next
            f_p = f_p.next.next
            
        #reverse slow pointer
        first_half = self.reverse(s_p)     
        
        #compare
        while(first_half != None and head != None):
            print(first_half.val)
            print(head.val)
            if(first_half.val != head.val):
                return False
            first_half = first_half.next
            head = head.next
        
        return True
    
    def reverse(self,c_p):
        
        prev_head = None
        
        while(c_p != None):
            temp = c_p.next
            c_p.next = prev_head
            prev_head = c_p
            c_p = temp
        
        return prev_head
```

But I'm having a hard time understanding why that code works.

Example: 1 -> 2 -> 2 -> 1

The idea according to this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOGh_3MTrdE) is that we take the first half of the list, reverse it, and compare.

The illustration says we will be comparing a pointer pointing to 1 -> 2 -> Null to a another pointer being 1 -> 2 -> Null after being reversed.

Although from what I can see, this is actually comparing first_half : 1 -> 2 -> 2 -> Null to
head : 1 -> 2 -> Null.

This code does pass all the test cases, but I would expect that the 2<sup>nd</sup> code (my modified version) should work too, but it doesn't:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
        #Null condition
        if head == None:
            return True
        
        #move fast and slow pointers
        s_p = head
        f_p = head
        while(f_p.next != None and f_p.next.next != None):
            s_p = s_p.next
            f_p = f_p.next.next
        
        #set s_p.next to Null
        s_p.next = None

        #reverse fast pointer
        second_half = self.reverse(f_p)
        
     
        
        #compare
        while(second_half != None and head != None):
            print(second_half.val)
            print(head.val)
            if(second_half.val != head.val):
                return False
            second_half = second_half.next
            head = head.next
        
        return True
    
    def reverse(self,c_p):
        
        prev_head = None
        
        while(c_p != None):
            temp = c_p.next
            c_p.next = prev_head
            prev_head = c_p
            c_p = temp
        
        return prev_head
```

In this way, all I do is reverse the second pointer : 2 -> 1 -> Null to 1 -> 2 -> Null

Now we can compare head to the reversed second half.

It does not pass the tests in LeetCode, but I am confused as to why not.

I understand this is an easy problem but I am still struggling.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your modified version 
 Your logic is correct but when your reverse function is defined to reverse the list from the parameter pass so, f_p would be pointing to the last element, not the middle element.
The leetcode version solution compares value from starting to values from the reversed second half.

Answer (score 0):

> The idea according to this YouTube video ... is that we take the first half of the list, reverse it, and compare.

This is a misunderstanding. It actually reverses the *second* half of the list. The correct code reverses the list that starts at `s_p` (slow pointer). This is *not* the first half of the list, but the *second* half. The first half would start exactly where the whole lists starts: at `head`. The loop that lets the `s_p` and `f_p` references walk along the list will end when `f_p` is near the end of the list, and `s_p` is therefore half-way the list.

Your code reverses the list that starts at `f_p` (fast pointer), but that pointer is referring to the last or one-but-last node in your list (look at the `while` condition), so if anything, it only reverses the final two nodes of the list! This is obviously not correct.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you.