# How to check for Treenode class where code is falling short?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am writing code to check whether a linked list is a palindrome:

My first question is, although my code is returning `false` for the `input l1=[1,2,2,1]`, when it should be returning `True`, I do not know how to check where the error lies.

Normally, I could run 'print' statements to check throughout the iterations or recursions, but for the below, as it is a TreeNode, I  don't know how to do this.

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
        l1 = head
        queue = []
        queue.append(l1.val)
        count = 0

        #finding mid-point of the linked list (count represents the number of connections in the linked list) 
        while l1:
            l1 = l1.next
            count += 1

        #Palindrome must have an even number of digits 
        if count % 2 == 0:
            return False
    
        count = (count + 1) // 2
        l1 = head
        
        #iterating over first half of the linked list and storing node values in a queue
        while count > 0:
            l1 = l1.next
            queue.append(l1.val)
            count -= 1
        #iterating over second half of the linked list to check if it is a palindrome by comparing each node value
        while l1:
            l1 = l1.next
            if l1.val == queue.pop():
                continue
    
            return False
    
        return True
```

Any ideas where the code is falling short? Or why I am getting 'false' for the input `l1=[1,2,2,1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first question is, although my code is returning false for the input `l1=[1,2,2,1]`, when it should be returning True, I do not know how to check where the error lies.

The code explicitly returns False for any input that has an even size. You have a comment stating *"Palindrome must have an even number of digits"*. But that is not true. Palindromes can be odd and even. So these lines should be removed from your code:

````
```
#Palindrome must have an even number of digits 
if count % 2 == 0:
    return False
```
````

> Any ideas where the code is falling short?

Besides the above mentioned issue, there is also this:

- The calculation of where the middle element is, is not correct: `count = (count + 1) // 2`. If for instance the input size is 5, then this results in 3, and so you'll add the next 3 elements to the queue. Add to that the one you already added at the very start of your function, and you notice that you add 4 elements to the queue. But actually you should only add 2 to the queue, and the 3rd element should be skipped. It would also make more sense to not treat the first node differently: don't add that node to the queue at the start of the function.
- Your loops always *start* by doing `l1 = l1.next`. But this is bad habit. In the following loop it will lead to problems:

  ```
  while l1:
       l1 = l1.next
       if l1.val
           // ...
  ```

  At a certain moment `l1` will become `None` in that assignment, and then `l1.val` will be an invalid attribute access. You should design your loops in a way that `l1 = l1.next` is the *last* statement in the loop's body, so that the `while` condition will kick in *right after* that assignment.

Here is your code adapted with those issues corrected:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
        l1 = head
        queue = []

        count = 0
        while l1:
            l1 = l1.next
            count += 1

        l1 = head
        for _ in range(0, count // 2):
            queue.append(l1.val)
            l1 = l1.next
        
        if count % 2:  # skip the center element when the list has an odd size
            l1 = l1.next

        while l1:
            if l1.val != queue.pop():
                return False
            l1 = l1.next
        
        return True
```

> Normally, I could run 'print' statements to check throughout the iterations or recursions, but for the below, as it is a `TreeNode`, I don't know how to do this.

This is indeed not so easy. I like to start such code challenges by resolving that difficulty first by adding some utility methods to the `ListNode` class:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

    # Make it easy to iterate over the list nodes
    def __iter__(self):
        visited = set()  # Let's detect loops to avoid infinite iteration
        node = self
        while node and not id(node) in visited:
            visited.add(id(node))
            yield node
            node = node.next
        if node:
            yield node
            yield None  # indication of loop

    # Use the above to iterate the values (not the node objects)
    def values(self):
        for node in self:
            if node:
                yield node.val
            else:
                yield "cycle!"

    # This will make it easy to print a list
    def __repr__(self):
        return " → ".join(map(str, self.values())) 

    # Allow to create a list from provided parameter values
    @classmethod
    def fromvalues(cls, *values):
        head = None
        for val in reversed(values):
            head = cls(val, head)
        return head
```

Now a test can look like this:

```
head = ListNode.fromvalues(1, 2, 2, 1)
print(head)
res = Solution().isPalindrome(head)
print(res)
```

## Better algorithm

Although your algorithm works (after some corrections), using a standard list (`queue`) to solve it goes against the spirit of the challenge: then you might as well put *all* the values in such a standard list, and do the palindrome check on that standard list.

You can solve this without a list, by reversing one half of the linked list. See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968942/5459839) and for instance [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67652949/leetcode-234-palindrome-linkedlist/67653130#67653130).